# GIT REBASE delete old commits

Tags: git-rebase

I have 4 Branches.

1. **Main Branch**
2. **Branch A** (based on main)
3. **Branch B** (based on main)
4. **Branch C** (based on main)

If i update the main branch, i make allways a "**git rebase**" on branch a,b,c. **This works great!!**
But now 2 Month later, Branch A have over 1000 commits.

How i can delete this 1000 commits? I dont need this anymore. Because the problem is, on every "**git rebase**" my vscode must update this 1000 commits. I like reset this to 0 commits.
Many thanks.

I like reset this to 0 commits

Comment: I don't understand how your workflow is. What do you mean with "I rebase main on a, b, c"? This also contradicts the list which states that "a is based on main". If you rebase "main on a", then "main is based on a", not the other way round. You can only rebase "on" a single branch (and rebasing does not increase the number of commits). If you don't need the commits of a branch, simply delete the branch; because honestly, what's the point in keeping a branch from which you don't need the commits?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the commits of branch anymore, simply delete it:

```
git branch -d name-of-branch-to-delete
```

or recreate it at another specified commit/ref:

```
git branch -f name-of-branch-to-reset new-head-commit-of-branch
# e.g. git branch -f branch-a main
```